# Android Delete Query

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm attempting to delete all rows in one table that do not have a corresponding ID in another table.  Since apparently SQLite does not support joins in deletes I am trying to do something along these lines:

```
    DELETE FROM my_table WHERE my_id NOT IN (SELECT _id FROM my_table2);
```

However, I apparently can not use rawQuery since it returns a cursor so I have to use the delete function.  I'm having some trouble getting this working.  Here is the query I'm trying:

```
    mDb.delete("my_table", "my_id NOT IN ?", new String[]{"(SELECT _id FROM my_table2)"});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You shouldn't use a .rawQuery, as you stated, but you can use .execSQL() to accomplish it. I regularly use it for deletions myself.

Comment: @mah can you plz explain how to use .execSQL for deletion ...i tried it threw error to me .Plz

Comment: The doc on `.execSQL` says "Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE." Why does this still work for those statements?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to execute your select and dynamically combine your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use execSQL instead rawQuery because rawQuery is used for the statement that return data and execSQL is used for the statements that don't return data like DELETE