# difference between rawquery and execSQL in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the exact difference between using rawquery and execSQL ??
While writing a query in android activity, when to use rawquery and when to use execSQL ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

From API documentation:

---

[`void execSQL (String sql)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29)

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

[`void execSQL (String sql, Object[] bindArgs)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[]%29)

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.

The documentation is inconsistent but they behave both the same. Documentation of the latter is more in depth.

---

[`Cursor rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)

> Runs the provided SQL and returns a Cursor over the result set.

---

Uses for `rawQuery` are:

- You want to query the database with a `SELECT` statement.
  => `rawQuery("SELECT ...` returns a set of rows and columns in a `Cursor`.

  - It's more efficient to use [`DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(SQLiteDatabase, String, String[])`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) or [`DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#stringForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) in cases there is only a 1x1 query result, like from `SELECT count(*) FROM table` (which also has it's own dedicated method: [`DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29)) - this skips creation of a `Cursor` object & simplifies code since there is also nothing to close, moveToNext, etc.
- Special cases like `PRAGMA table_info` that returns data in rows (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721484/get-name-and-type-from-pragma-table-info))
- Note: Do **not** use `rawQuery` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` or anything else that modifies the database. You'll run into ["Why does a delete rawQuery need a moveToFirst in order to actually delete the rows?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211158/why-does-a-delete-rawquery-need-a-movetofirst-in-order-to-actually-delete-the-ro). Reason being that queries can defer reading the result until needed (= access to the cursor) which means for SQLite delaying [execution of the statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html).

Uses for `execSQL` are:

- You have "instructions" for the database. Like `CREATE TABLE` (or any other `CREATE` statement, e.g. `CREATE INDEX`), `DROP`, `PRAGMA`s that set properties rather than returning them, ...
- `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`  when you're not interested in the amount of rows modified or the row id of the last insert.

  - When you need those, either use the `update()`, `insert()`, `delete()` methods or use a second statement to read those: `DatabaseUtils.longForQuery` with either `SELECT last_insert_rowid()` or `SELECT changes()`. Both return only 1 integer value. (see ["Get updated rows count from SQLite in Android using a raw query?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659673/get-updated-rows-count-from-sqlite-in-android-using-a-raw-query) and [“SELECT last_insert_rowid()” returns always “0”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302276/select-last-insert-rowid-returns-always-0))
- Anything else that relies on executing a statement.

Comment: got it clear .. execSQL doesnt return anything and used for creating,updating etc .. and rawQuery returns cursors etc.

Answer (score 12):

if you want to execute something in database without concerning its output (e.g create/alter tables), then use **execSQL**, but if you are expecting some results in return against your query (e.g. select records) then use **rawQuery**