# Using execSQL for INSERT operation in Android SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667031/difference-between-rawquery-and-execsql-in-android-sqlite-database)  I know `execSQL()`  executes a single SQL statement that is not a `SELECT` or any other SQL statement that returns data. It is also mentioned that `execSQL()` should not be used for inserting.

But I'm using `execSQL()` for inserting like:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO LIST VALUES('খবর');"); //where LIST is a table
```

This is working perfectly for me (there is no `SELECT` statement with this `INSERT`), but I was told not to use this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517550/sqlite-connection-in-android/10517929#10517929).

So, my question is: **does the `INSERT` statement return a value even though there is no `SELECT` statement attached to it?**

Comment: Try to add double Quote ("খবর")

Comment: try this example with code http://www.blazin.in/2016/02/understanding-sqlite-database-in-android.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it, it is just not recommended because you won't receive any information that might be generated by the DB.  The methods you are supposed to use return codes/cursors/other info to let you know what happened so you can deal with them if there is a problem.

The key is this line in the `execSQL` docs:

```
It has no means to return any data (such as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're encouraged to use insert...
```

The important word there is "encouraged".  You *can* use `execSQL` for any SQL command, but you get no feedback on the process, which makes it rather dangerous to use for something where you should get feedback (unless you don't care than an insert failed, or only 2 of 5 records got updated).

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` statements do not return result sets, at least not in Sqlite.

The Android docs says this about [`execSQL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29):

> Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL
>   statement that returns data. It has no means to return any data (such
>   as the number of affected rows). Instead, you're **encouraged** to use
>   insert(String, String, ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues,
>   String, String[]), et al, when possible.

I am not an Android programmer, but I would certainly not be encouraged to use the `insert` function instead of `execSQL`, *except* if I want to retrieve the [`rowid`](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) of the inserted record. Furthermore, the quoted explanation is at best confusing as it implies that insert could return some data.

Note that it's possible that there is some side effect that would make `insert` a better choice than `execSQL`, or that "best practices" dictate you use `insert`.

Comment: does INSERT statement that contains a SELECT statement like : `INSERT INTO suppliers
(supplier_id, supplier_name)
SELECT account_no, name
FROM customers
WHERE city = 'Newark';` returns value?

Comment: No; "INSERT INTO .. SELECT ..." is an INSERT statement just as "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ..." is.

Comment: I think the SELECT statement returns value which is used by INSERT statement IMHO.

Comment: You asked about the `INSERT` statement: "does INSERT statement ... returns a value?"

Comment: No. The INSERT Statement does not return a value