# Difference between getWritableDatabase() and database.execSQL("INSERT INTO table (column name) values(value));

Tags: android, sqlite, getwritabledatabase

I noticed two methods for insert data into database tables.

Example:
`getWritableDatabase()` method and `database.execSQL("INSERT INTO table (column name) values(value))`.

What is the difference between these two methods? Which one is best?

Comment: Umm... `getWritableDatabase` *returns* that `database` variable that you need for `database.execSQL`... What do you mean difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using execSQL for INSERT operation in Android SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519268/using-execsql-for-insert-operation-in-android-sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getWritableDatabase()` does not insert data into your database.

It will just open your database for writing.

If you want to insert data into your db, just call SQL (as you did with `INSERT INTO ...`) or call `database.insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values); /* if your database is from SQLiteDatabase type */`

Hope it answers your question, Darkball60

Comment: No problem, always there if you need help ^^

Comment: I have another doubt that, in some where i found db.insert() method for inserting data , and in somewhere use sqlite query for inserting data. What is the difference between them? Which one is best? @Darkball60

Comment: `db.insert()` returns the id from where the content have been added in the database. A simple query doesn't really return this, if you use `db.execSQL(String SQL);`

Comment: Thank you Darkball60. This is a great information for me.

Comment: No problem. If you have any question, I'll be here to answer it as soon as possible. ^^