# "optimize" command in sqlite fts3 on android makes "MATCH" doesn't work

Tags: android-sqlite, fts4

I am creating a fts4 table in android , I batch insert large number of rows then optimize as recommended in [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#optimize)

I use the following code in android

```
public void indexFts() {
      SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
      db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pageTextSearch USING  fts4(content=\"\", page)");
 db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            SQLiteStatement populateFTS_Statement = db.compileStatement(INSERT INTO pageTextSearch(docid,page)VALUES (?, ?)); //pre-compiled sql statement


            while (allPagesCursor.moveToNext()) {
                populateFTS_Statement.clearBindings();
                populateFTS_Statement.bindLong(1, allPagesCursor.getLong(0));
                populateFTS_Statement.bindString(2, allPagesCursor.getString(1));
                populateFTS_Statement.executeInsert();

            }
            db.execsql( INSERT INTO pageTextSearch(pageTextSearch)VALUES('optimize'));

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();

        }
}
```

now when I query the fts table with match I get 0 result whatever the query
for example:

```
  db.rawQuery(SELECT docid FROM pageTextSearch WHERE page MATCH ?
                , new String[]{"a"});
```

will give an empty cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot to spot the error (the transaction,the fts contentless table and the precompiles SQL)
The problem actually is with using execsql, using rawQuery instead solved the problem
I didn't find this behaviour documented in the android execsql documenationn
see this [question for discussion about using execsql to insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519268/using-execsql-for-insert-operation-in-android-sqlite)

so the working code is

```
 db.rawQuery( INSERT INTO pageTextSearch(pageTextSearch)VALUES('optimize'),null);
```