# "SELECT last_insert_rowid()" returns always "0"

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem with "last_insert_rowid()".

In my DB-Helper-Class I am doing the following:

```
public int getLastID() {
    final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM "+ DATABASE_TABLE5;
    Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    int ID = cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();
    return ID;
}
```

But when I call this in my intent:

```
int ID = mDbHelper.getLastID(); 
Toast.makeText(this, "LastID: " + ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I get always "0" back. That can not be, cause I have a lot of entries in my DB and the autoincrement value should be much higher.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the row id immediately after your last insert? As I understand the function, it will only return a row id if you are using the same open connection as your last insert.

Comment: Oh, than I missunderstood the function. That could it be. What I wanted to do is get the highest ID in the table. Is there another function for this?

Comment: @JohnP - thanks, your comment helped me locate a bug.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, that was the right hint John ;-)

The query should look like this:

```
public int getHighestID() {
final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(_id) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE5;
Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
cur.moveToFirst();
int ID = cur.getInt(0);
cur.close();
return ID;
}
```

Comment: Hm. Supposing this a single client architecture. If you have multiple clients reading/writing to the DB, MAX(_id) may be different

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to put table name with `last_insert_rowid()` it will automatically select last inserted id from session. so you can just simply use this function as well.

```
public int getHighestID() {
    final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT last_insert_rowid()";
    Cursor cur = mDb.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    int ID = cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();
    return ID;
}
```