# Get name and type from PRAGMA table_info()

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In my android app, I need to get `name` and `type` from the result when I'm getting after execute the command `PRAGMA table_info(table_name)`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's as simple as that (`db` is your `SQLiteDatabase` object and `tableName` should be set to the correct table name inside your database):

```
String tableName = ""; // your table name
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("PRAGMA table_info(" + tableName + ")", null);
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        System.out.println("name: " + c.getString(1) + " type: " + c.getString(2));
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
c.close();
```