# Dynamic select statement for SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, select

I'm building an API, for this API i want to have my database handler as dynamically as possible.

I do have the update and insert query's dynamic by using the SQLiteDatabase class .insert and .update functions, but there is no such a thing for select.

Would i have to build my own method to do this (just like the insert or update methods) or is there something I'm missing which will make this problem cost me a lot less trouble?

The language I'm using is JAVA.

Comment: Show us what have you done so far and tell us what are the specific problems you're having with your current implementation. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You can construct a list of column names in a table using Pragam, this may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721484/get-name-and-type-from-pragma-table-info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, so I went on looking and came to the following conclusion:

SQLiteDatabase has a method called `.query('lots of Args')` which is basically a select statement, I will use this and it will work the way I intended to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are functions like rawQuery in which you can use the select clause and infact many more such functions. Go through the SQLiteDatabase class documentation properly.

Comment: I know this one exists, but the problem here is, that is isn´t as easy to make it dynamically as the update and insert functions, while it should be able to.