# why c.moveToFirst() won't skip the first row

Tags: android, sqlite, database-cursor

I always *use the code below* to get all the informations
But I have question that **c.movetoNext** lead to skip the first row of result set
Please tell me ***what really happens behind the surface*** so that I can fully understand it

```
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor c = db.query("pic", null, null, null, null,null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(c.movetoNext)
    {
    //do something
    //example: String a=c.getString(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're calling `moveToFirst()`, which positions the cursor on the first row, then your while loop calls `moveToNext()` before entering the loop, which results in the first row being skipped.

You can solve it with either a do...while loop, or a for loop such as

```
for( c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext() ) {
    // Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A late answer, but hopefully useful to others finding this page. I've been using an: "if () do {  } while();" loop. The "moveToFirst()" function returns false if no rows were returned in the cursor. The "moveToNext()" function returns false when past end of cursor:

```
Cursor c = db.query(......);

if (c.moveToFirst()) do {
   data = c.getString(0) // eg. get value from first column in cursor
   // do something more
} while (c.moveToNext());

c.close();
```

(which is similar to TactMayers' answer).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cursor](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) documentation, "query... Returns: A Cursor object, which is positioned before the first entry". It further seems that [queries get executed only when methods are called on the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211158/why-does-a-delete-rawquery-need-a-movetofirst-in-order-to-actually-delete-the-ro). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
c.moveToFirst();
```

This line move the cursor to the first row.

```
while(c.movetoNext)
```

After running this line of code, the cursor will move to next row (row 2 for the first run of the while loop.) So by the time the code enter the loop, the cursor is pointing to row 2 already and can never access the first row.

Try replacing the while loop like this

```
do {
    // do something
} while(c.movetoNext())
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not have to call **c.moveToFirst();** at all

Comment: And why would that be? Do you have any references for that statement?

Comment: Because initial index is `-1` and `moveToNext()` on that simply means index 0, see http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#257.