# Simple DELETE statement did not work in SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-delete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Delete Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337764/android-delete-query)

I've db and right now it has 17 records. 
This is my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db=openOrCreateDatabase("mydb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
c= db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM tbl1 where cat='12'",null);
db.close();
```

It's a really simple query but every time I run the app on emulator, it's runs perfectly without any error but I doesn't remove anything either.

Could anyone helps me with what is the problem ?

Comment: Does it work if you try it with the `sqlite3` command-line tool? And of what type are the values in the `cat` column?

Comment: use db.execSQL() instead of db.rawQuery

Answer (score 5):

db.execSQL("DELETE FROM tbl1 where cat=12");

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try for this code,

```
db.delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs);
```

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null)
```

problem in your code - '12'.
Insert changes:

```
c= db.rawQuery("DELETE FROM tbl1 where cat=12",null);
```