# Android Sqlite subquery does not return any value

Tags: android, sqlite, subquery

I am using the following query to get the list of item

```
Query="Select * from Item_List where idSubcategory = (Select _id from SubCategory_List where Name = ?)";
c = db.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { Search });
```

But it is returning no result.

I ran this query on the database which I pulled from the device as well as emulator. There I am getting proper result, But when I run it on device no data is returned.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check that 'Search' contains the value you think it does? Otherwise I would try embedding the actual value of 'Search' within the Query string in place of the ? to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Dhiraj Tayade did you solved your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try a different way? Use **execSQL()** as explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337764/android-delete-query). It is exactly the same problem.

EDIT

Unfortunately i didn't notice that execSQL() return no data (the work day is ending, finally!). The only solution i have is to do a first query and the result of this one will be the parameter of second query.

EDIT 2

Try to add "IN" to your query, like this:

```
Query = "Select * from Item_List where idSubcategory in (Select _id from SubCategory_List where Name = ?)"
```

Comment: I actually have a complex query. `select * from Item_List where _id IN (
  select idItem from TopItem_List where IdCustomer = (
   select _id from Cust_List where Name =  '?'
  )
 )`

Comment: @DhirajTayade that's why i think it is not working; add your "search" to the String query and then use .execSQL().

Comment: `execSql` cannot return data.

Comment: Doh, my mistakes, sorry.

Comment: so whats the solution. I dont think I the query has error neither is the database problem. where is the problem ?